# Pass a function template to other function

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Suppose I have a function that does something on an arbitrary container type (C++11):

```
template<class containerType>
void bar( containerType& vec ) {

        for (auto i: vec) {
                std::cout << i << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I can call this function from another function like this:

```
void foo() {
        std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3 };
        bar(vec);
}
```

Now suppose I have different functions just like bar, and I want to pass one of these functions to foo, then foo would look something like this:

```
template<class funcType>
void foo( funcType func ) {
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3 };
    func(vec);
}
```

However, calling foo like this:

```
foo(bar);
```

does not work (pretty clear, since bar is not a function but a function template). Is there any nice solution to this? How must I define foo to make this work?

EDIT: here is a minimal compileable example, as demanded in the comments...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template<class containerType>
void bar( containerType& vec ) {

        for (auto i: vec) {
                std::cout << i << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename funcType>
void foo(funcType func) {

        std::vector<int> vals = { 1, 2, 3 };
        func(vals);

}

int main() {
        // foo( bar );  - does not work.
}
```

Comment: you are missing minimal compilable example

Comment: Why do you use use function pointers? I believe that using an functor would be better here.

Comment: @AlexTheo Thanks for your comment. Of course, using functors the solution is simple! Bob posted a similar solution as an answer. I'll go with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? (not fully awake, might miss the point)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct Test{
template<class containerType>
static void apply( containerType& vec ) {

        for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
                std::cout << *it << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
}
};

template<class FuncStruct>
void foo() {

        std::vector<int> vals;
        vals.push_back(1);
        FuncStruct::apply(vals);

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    foo<Test>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just as @AlexTheo pointed out in the comments, using a functor is probably the easiest solution here.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that foo works with a vector of int, you can pass `bar< std::vector<int> >` function.

A reasonable solution would be for the module that defines `foo` to also define typedef for the container used. Then you don't even need `bar` to be a template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd prefer that the caller of foo does not know how foo works internally - he just knows that he has to pass a function that operates on arbitrary containers.

Comment: @fdlm but the function does not operate on arbitrary containers. It is a template function, so think of it as creating the function for the required container type at compile time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, but I don't want the caller of foo to know which container foo uses internally. So the template instanciation has to take place in the foo function itself

Comment: @JurajBlaho: That would be a reasonable solution, but I personally prefer the functor-solution, as it exposes less internals to the user of the foo function.

Answer (score 4):

Online demo at http://ideone.com/HEIAl

This allows you to do `foo(bar)`. Instead of passing in a template-function or a template-class, we pass in a non-template class that has a template-member-function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

struct {
    template<class containerType>
    void operator() ( containerType& vec ) {

        for (auto i = vec.begin(); i!=vec.end(); ++i) {
                std::cout << *i << ", ";
        }

        std::cout << '\n';

    }
} bar;

template<typename funcType>
void foo(funcType func) {

        std::vector<int> vals = { 1, 2, 3 };
        func(vals);

}

int main() {
        foo( bar );
}
```