# Why can std::apply call a lambda but not the equivalent template function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

The following code snippet (compiled using gcc 6.3.0 on OS X with -std=c++17) demonstrates my conundrum:

```
#include <experimental/tuple>

template <class... Ts>
auto p(Ts... args) {
  return (... * args);
}

int main() {
  auto q = [](auto... args) {
    return (... * args);
  };

  p(1,2,3,4); // == 24
  q(1,2,3,4); // == 24

  auto tup = std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4);
  std::experimental::apply(q, tup); // == 24
  std::experimental::apply(p, tup); // error: no matching function for call to 'apply(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::tuple<int, int, int, int>&)'
}
```

Why can apply successfully deduce the call to the lambda but not the call to the template function? Is this the expected behavior and, if so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a function template to other function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9308749/636019)?

Comment: That question refers to passing a template function to another function -- this question refers to using apply on a generic lambda (which works) versus a template function (which doesn't).

Comment: "*That question refers to passing a template function to another function*" Like passing `p` (a function template) to `apply` (another function (template))..?

Comment: well the answer to that question does not explain why exactly functor class works, and it doesn't mention the fact that generic labmda is the same thing as the functor class, but otherwise yeah, that's it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between the two is that `p` is a function template, while `q` - a generic lambda - is pretty much a closure class with a templated **call operator**.

Although the definition of said call operator is very much the same as `p` definition, the closure class is not a template at all, and therefore it doesn't stay in a way of template argument resolution for `std::experimental::apply`.

This can be checked by defining `p` as a functor class:

```
struct p
{
   auto operator()(auto... args)
   { return (... * args); }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you for clearly elucidating the difference between a generic lambda and template function -- that will be a helpful tool in the future.